# Marginnote in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, marginnote

I use a star in the margin section to sections header to indicate more advanced or more important material.

I use the `marginnote` package for that purpose, as in the following example :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\section{Context}

If you wanna go somewhere and you don't have railroad fare, plane fare, train fare, boat fare, or don't have no fare, period.

\section{Method}
\marginnote{*}[-25pt]

There's one way of gettin there, I been using the method for 25 years or more, me and old Sonny, and it seems to have paid off. To a higher debt, man. Just walk on.

\end{document}
```

Now, I would like the star to appear next to the corresponding header in the table of content. How could this be achieved ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**See the better version below the first version!**

One quick way: Use the optional argument of `\section`, but this tedious!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\section{Context}

If you wanna go somewhere and you don't have railroad fare, plane fare, train fare, boat fare, or don't have no fare, period.

\section[{\protect\marginnote{*}[0pt]}Method]{Method}


There's one way of gettin there, I been using the method for 25 years or more, me and old Sonny, and it seems to have paid off. To a higher debt, man. Just walk on.

\end{document}
```

**Better version**

I've used `xparse` and added renewed the definition of `\section`, adding an optional `*` star argument at the end of the `\section` command!

`\section{foo}` → no star in the marginpar

`\section{foo}*` → star in the marginpar

`\section[bar]{foo}` → no star in the marginpar, optional `ToC` entry `bar`

`\section[bar]{foo}*`→ star in the marginpar, optional `ToC` entry `bar`

See the output -- remember to compile twice!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\let\LaTeXStandardSection\section

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{soms}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \LaTeXStandardSection{#3}
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \IfBooleanTF{#4}{%
        \LaTeXStandardSection[{\protect\marginnote{*}}#2]{#3}
      }{%
        \LaTeXStandardSection[#2]{#3}
      }%
    }{%
      \IfBooleanTF{#4}{%
        \LaTeXStandardSection[{\protect\marginnote{*}}#3]{#3}
      }{%
        \LaTeXStandardSection[#3]{#3}
      }%
    }%
  }%
}



\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\section{Context}

If you wanna go somewhere and you don't have railroad fare, plane fare, train fare, boat fare, or don't have no fare, period.

\section{Method}*

\section[Other content]{Other content}

\section[Important stuff]{Other important stuff}*



There's one way of gettin there, I been using the method for 25 years or more, me and old Sonny, and it seems to have paid off. To a higher debt, man. Just walk on.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty convenient.

Comment: @AlfredM.: Yes, it is ;-) I could be extended to provide an optional vertical shift of the marginpar, if needed

Answer (score 2):

You could add the marginnote to the section text:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{marginnote,etoolbox}
\reversemarginpar
\robustify\marginnote

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\section{Context}

If you wanna go somewhere and you don't have railroad fare, plane fare, train fare, boat fare, or don't have no fare, period.

\section{Method\marginnote{*}}


There's one way of gettin there, I been using the method for 25 years or more, me and old Sonny, and it seems to have paid off. To a higher debt, man. Just walk on.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, I did not knew about robustify.